# Access VBA check that period between two date fields does not cross specific date

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an Access form that requires users to enter a [Start Date] and [End Date]. Before saving the record, I would like to validate these fields to ensure that the period entered does not cross the 30th of June in any given year.

In my head I am thinking that the procedure would check the [Start Date] first, if it is between January 1 and June 30, then [End Date] must be less than or equal to June 30 *of that year*. If [Start Date] is between July 1 and December 31, then the [End Date] must be less than or equal to June 30 *of the following year*.

I'm am not sure how to express this in VBA so any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it may be something like this:

```
Public Function IsDateValid(dtStart As Date, dtEnd As Date) As Boolean
Dim dtDeadline As Date

dtDeadline = DateSerial(Year(dtStart), 6, 30)
If dtStart > dtDeadline Then
    dtDeadline = DateSerial(Year(dtStart) + 1, 6, 30)
End If
IsDateValid = dtEnd < dtDeadline
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

You could follow this method:

```
Dim StartDate As Date
Dim EndDate   As Date
Dim CheckDate As Date 
Dim OK        As Boolean

' Pass values of StartDate and EndDate here.
' StartDate = ?
' EndDate = ?

' Find June 30th of the current or the next year of StartDate.
CheckDate = DateSerial(Year(StartDate) + (Month(StartDate) - 1) \ 6, 6, 30)  

If DateDiff("d", EndDate, CheckDate) >= 0 Then
    ' EndDate falls before or on CheckDate.
    OK = True
End If

' Return value of OK.
```

Please note the the *backslash* performs an integer division.

Comment: Thanks for feedback, I was able to achieve my aim with the variation of solution below